# Unable to connect server using flask and docker

Tags: python, docker, flask

I have a problem with my app flask; i'm using an interpreter docker in pycharm, and I have already a docker image. When i run my app, the server doesn'connect... the following files are stored in directory 'ca_guy'. This is the code:

guy.py:

```
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template, flash, request, redirect, url_for
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename

from orange_cb_recsys.content_analyzer.ca_guy.parser_dataset import Parser


app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True


path_dataset = None

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')


@app.route('/u_files')  # methods=['GET', 'POST']
def item_files():
    return render_template('u_files.html')


@app.route('/u_files', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_dataset():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        f = request.files['file']
        path = os.path.abspath(f.filename)
        global path_dataset
        path_dataset = path
        print(path_dataset)

        return render_template('u_files.html')

def extract_field():
    global path_dataset
    list_field = []
    parser = Parser(path_dataset)
    if path_dataset.endswith('.json'):
        list_field = parser.from_file_json()
    if path_dataset.endswith('.csv'):
        list_field = parser.from_file_csv()

    return list_field


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5001)
```

DOCKERFILE:

```
FROM python:3.8.3
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /ca_guy
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5001
ENTRYPOINT [ "python" ]
CMD [ "guy.py" ]
```

requieremnts.txt:

```
flask
```

Comment: What URL are you trying to connect to?  From where?  How are you launching the container?  What is the exact error you're getting?

Comment: When i launch my flask app and click on the URL, It says 'Unable to connect to '0.0.0.0:5001'

Comment: 0.0.0.0 is a special IPv4 address that means "everywhere"; it doesn't make sense to include it in a URL.  How are you launching the container?  What's your host OS and what "kind" of Docker are you using (in particular, is it Docker Toolbox)?

Answer (score 0):

Modify your Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8.3
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5001
ENTRYPOINT [ "python" ]
CMD [ "guy.py" ]
```

To build this:

```
docker build -t DOCKER-NAME:latest .
```

To run:

```
docker run -p 5001:5001 DOCKER-NAME
```

Comment: for 'DOCKER-NAME' you mean the image that i've already created?

Comment: Yes, is the name